# How to sanitize user created filenames for a networked application?

Tags: security, filenames, sanitize

I'm working on an instant messaging app, where users can receive files from their friends.

The names of the files received are set by the sender of the file, and multiple files can be sent together with the possibility of subdirectories. For example, two files sent together might be "1" and "sub/2" such that the downloaded results should be like "downloads/1" and "downloads/sub/2".

I'm worried about the security implications of this. Right off the top of my head, two potentially dangerous filnames would be something like "../../../somethingNasty" or "~/somethingNasty" for Unix-like users. Other potential issues that cross my mind are filenames with characters that are unsupported on the target filesystem, but that seems much harder and may just be better to ignore?

I'm considering stripping received filenames for ".." and "~" but this type of blacklist approach where I individually think of problem cases hardly seems like the recipe for good security. What's the recommended way to sanitize filenames to ensure nothing sinister happens?

If it makes a difference, my app is running on C++ with the QT framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's wiser to replace ".." with say XXX and ~ with say YYY. This way you convert any invalid path to a perfectly valid path. I.e. if the user wants to upload "../../../somethingNasty" - no problems, let him upload the file and store it in XXX/XXX/XXX/somethingNasty.

Or even better, you can encode all nonalphanumeric characters (except slashes) with %XY where XY is hexidecimal code of the character. This way you would have %2E%2E/%2E%2E/%2E%2E/SomethingNasty